# Call function in Remotable class

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

I have a remotable class derived from `MarshalByRefObject`.I have two public functions in it say `TestMethod1` and T`estMethod2`. I am invoking these from an HttpHandler and it works fine. Now I have added a new function `TestMethod3` that is similar to the two methods mentioned before. But, while calling this function from the same handler and getting an exception which says "undable to find the .exe for this application", where the exe is the process in which the remote object runs.

```
class HttpHandlerClass : IHttpHandler
{
    RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownClientType(typeof(RemoteClass),"ipc://completeurl");

    RemoteClass rc = new RemoteClass();

    if (condition1)
        rc.TestMethod1();

    else 
        rc.TestMethod3();
}

class RemoteClass: MarshalByRefObject
{
   public void TestMethod1(int a) { }
   public void TestMethod2(string b) { }
   public void TestMethod3(string c) { }
}
```

No clue why. Seems to me I need to make some changes(dont know where) so that the TestMethod3 is recognized.

Any ideas?

> Output: Could not load file or assembly 'Project.exe, version=1.0.0.0, Culture-neutral, publickeytoken=blahblah' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Just noticed, it is looking for an older version of the Project.exe and not the one whihc is being executed.

Comment: Could you provide the complete exception? and code snippets if possible? to understand the problem well.

Comment: were you aware that Remoting has been deprecated in favor of WCF?

Comment: John - Well I did not, but I need to stick to reoting here just because thats the standard followed.

Comment: Ok. I just discovered something. If I just add a function doesnt do much and just accesses members in the same class, it works fine. However, if I access a function of another class then it throws that exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ICE](http://www.zeroc.com/ice.html) instead? I struggled for months in the same situation as you, then ended up solving everything within a week when I switched architectures.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot because its existing code used by others as well that I need to update and I cannot switch to ICE.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, but I've run into this issue before with remoting.

Are you sure the `.exe` you're remoting to is up to date? It's possible you didn't copy a compiled file to the expected location, and then the old methods would still work, but the new one will break completely...